# Can I fix a mold problem in wall-to-wall carpet myself?

Tags: mold, carpet, air-quality

Recently, an apartment-mate of mine flooded my toilet quite severely. It completely covered the bathroom floor (tiles) and seeped into the carpet. I'd say a good 6-8 feet of carpet was soaked in water. Fortunately, the toilet water was just clear water so it's just water that got onto the carpet. I'm not sure how much of the water she got off the carpet but the area around the affected carpet has been smelling pretty bad. I'm certain there's mold/mildew under the carpet which is the source of the odor.

The carpet is non-removeable and I have no steam/deep cleaner or dry/wet vacuum but I do have a standard vacuum.

How would I get rid of the odor and/or the mold(/mildew?) with limited supplies?

Do I need to hire a professional to do the job for me? Or can this be done by myself.

Comment: Hire a carpet cleaner?

Comment: I purchased a small hand-held dry/wet vacuum for $20 so I'll try to fix it by myself for now. If the baking soda + vinegar action doesn't get rid of the odor and/or mold, then I'll look into a carpet cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't unless you will buy pro cleaning equipment.  First if your carpet has mold it is settled into the pad.  Carpet has to be rolled up and affected pad replaced.  Subfloor cleaned and dried too.  A pro cleaner would scorch your carpet - you can't get the heat from rental cleaners.